# MIMIC III: timestamps are shifted by several years... is that normal?

Tags: mimic-iii

Background: downloaded the MIMIC III data sets from PhysioNet in csv form. Opened ADMISSIONS data table in MS Excel, only to find that the time stamps have been shifted by many years.

e.g., ADMITTIME
"2191-02-25 20:30:00"
"2111-08-29 03:03:00"

Does any one have an idea as to how this may have happened?

Comment: That is in Excel. What do  you see if you look directly in the CSV?

Comment: Does anyone know when I can get the MIMIC III data after submitting a request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following paper provides important background information on the MIMIC-III dataset: http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201635. The point below addresses your question:

> "dates were shifted into the future by a random offset for each individual patient ... resulting in stays which occur sometime between the years 2100 and 2200."

Please also refer to the section on "Times" in the MIMIC-III documentation:
http://mimic.physionet.org/mimicdata/time/